# Checking if multiple instances of a Java application are running (without preventing them)

Tags: java

I've seen plenty of examples of how to prevent Java applications, such as locking a file or creating  a socket.

How do I allow multiple instances to run, but check if another one is running?

The reason I need to do this is that I want to clean a temporary folder on exit, but not if there is another process running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/package-summary.html) and check for running virtual machines like explained in this [blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_attach_api)

> The other manner of acquiring a VirtualMachine is to ask for the **list of virtual machines known to the system, and then pick the specific one you are interested** in, typically by name:
>
> ```
>   String name = ...
>   List vms = VirtualMachine.list();
>   for (VirtualMachineDescriptor vmd: vms) {
>       if (vmd.displayName().equals(name)) {
>           VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(vmd.id());
>           String agent = ...
>           vm.loadAgent(agent);
>           // ...
>       }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any IPC you like. For example, create `/tmp/you_app_name_flag.$$` files ( $$ means pid ) and verify existance of `/tmp/you_app_name_flag.*` on your app's start.

Comment: Issue with that approach is that if the program or operating system crashes, the file will still exist.

Comment: afaik, when OS restarts, it clears /tmp. As for you app - remove your flag file not on exit only but in your signal handlers.